# Sorting date and time fields in ColdFusion cfgrid tag

Tags: coldfusion

I have a table with separate date and time fields which are displayed in a ColdFusion CFGRID using CFGRIDCOLUMN.  I'd like to be able to sort on date and then time.  Is there a way to sort on more than one column?  It sort of works by clicking to sort on the time column first and then the date column, but this is not reflected in the column header sort indicators.

I could combine the fields into a single datetime field and use Ext JS mask attributes to display the date and time in separate columns.  Am I making it too hard for myself by having the date and time in separate fields?

Comment: "Am I making it too hard for myself by having the date and time in separate fields?" Yes.  If you want flexibility, use jQuery w/ jqGrid

Comment: You could also make your own grid using tables.  I became an expert at that after my company said we weren't allowed to use CFGRIDs because they were to resource intensive.  That was for version 6 and 7, don't know if hey have improved for version 8 or 9

Comment: In response to your question regarding making it more difficult, yes, having the date and time in different columns does make it more difficult. However, you do not need to switch to jQuery w. jqGrid for 'flexibility'. CFGRID is nothing more than an EXTJS element, as such, we are able to do anything with CFGRID you can do with EXTJS grid, you just need to tap into the underlying JS objects to do so.